# Issue on Updating Geometric Network Weights - Error: -2147210918

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network

Using ArcGIS 10.4.1, I am trying to add New Weight (Bitgate Type) to an existing Geometric Network but after couple of minutes I am getting this message

> The network weights were not updated 
>   FDO error: -2147210918 
>   Cannot register as versioned on this database.

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include details on how you added the weight, and what you set?

Comment: Is your geometric network empty?  Does it contain feature classes?

Comment: See http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000006485